# how to install new bootsplash image in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does plymouth start so late?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79953/why-does-plymouth-start-so-late)

I tried configuring it by installing 'Super Boot Manager' and it applies correctly without giving any error messages but when i reboot the router, i still see blank screen and not bootsplash. Please help.

Comment: bump...anyone??