# Not seeing Plymouth graphical boot-up screen until end of boot process

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 14.04, plymouth

After reverting back from BURG to GNU GRUB2, I noticed that the purple Plymouth loading screen wasn't appearing until the very end of the boot-up process, when it flashed up for about a second.

Before this, the purple screen loaded with the Ubuntu logo and the dots at the bottom changing colour one by one.
Now, after selecting Ubuntu on the GRUB2 menu, I see a black screen for a long time (probably while Ubuntu is booting in the background), and then the purple screen shows up for a second and the dots change colour all at once. Then, it takes me to the log-in screen.

This is really bugging me, and I'd be grateful if anyone could help.
Thanks!

*Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Dual-booted alongside Windows 7
Toshiba Satellite C660-2EL*

Comment: take a look [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/03/how-to-get-plymouth-working-with-nvidia.html) if you do everything right as instructed it will work.

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish I have the same problem but instructions you posted are 4 years old. Are those instructions valid for Ubuntu 14.04 too?

Comment: @Alen I've done it myself on 14.04 it worked for me :-)

Comment: the only thing is `vbeinfo` in provided script will not work anymore you'll have to enter dimensions blindly but that's not a big deal just enter e.g. `1024x768-24` it depends on your display parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a tiresome internet-searching session, I **finally** managed to find my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/79959/289337
Thanks for the replies though. (By the way, JohnnyEnglish's method didn't work for me).