# Plymouth starts very late in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: plymouth

I am using Kubuntu 18.04. My problem is that while the boot takes ~30 seconds, the plymouth screen shows only for the later 2-3 seconds. Rest all the time the screen is black.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem with my old PC and https://askubuntu.com/a/79959 solved it a bit - that is to set `FRAMEBUFFER=y` in the initramfs. Things were better with Ubuntu 14.04 though.

Comment: Wow really? I mean one would imagine things works have moved forwards a bit by now

Comment: Things have definitely moved forward with modern HW from last few years(?). I was struggling with a laptop from 2011.

Comment: Yeah - modern hw with UEFI boot wasn't an issue. On a dell laptop that's couple of years old, boot is smooth & works like a charm. My desktop from 2012 - not so much.... even with this framebuffer thing, the boot ex is janky and bad.